# SQL Server - Replace() in a select * query

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure that does a "select * from view" and this output contains an inverted comma in one of the columns. I want to do a replace() to  remove the extra inverted comma but I cannot change the "select *" as this is a dynamic query that is used in different scenarios.

As evident, the following query does not work

```
select replace(*, '"', '') from ReportRegistry
```

Some help appreciated.

I wanted to know if there is any way I can remove the quotes without knowing the column names. I want them to be removed from all columns. The columns names are different in different cases.

The view is defined within the procedure differently in different cases. The dynamic colum names are added as text and them executed using sp_executesql.

Comment: If you cannot change the `select *` then what *can* you change?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any way I can remove the quotes without knowing the column names. I want them to be removed from all columns.

Comment: That depends entirely on what changes you can make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

--Dynamically build a list of column names for the view, separated by commas.
SELECT @ColNames = @ColNames + 
    CASE
        --Use the REPLACE function for "String" type data types.  Did I leave any data types out?
        --Change "x" to the character(s) you want to replace.
        WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR', 'NCHAR') THEN 'REPLACE([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '], ''x'', '''') AS [' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '],'
        --All other data types.
        ELSE '[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '],'
    END
--In addition to user tables, views are included in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (and in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES).
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'ReportRegistry'
--Retain original order of the view's columns.
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION

--Remove last comma
SET @ColNames = LEFT(@ColNames, LEN(@ColNames) - 1)

EXEC ('SELECT ' + @ColNames + ' FROM ReportRegistry ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(TargetColumnName, '"', '')
       ,Column2
       ,Column3
       ,..... and so on..... 
from ReportRegistry
```

Comment: As mentioned, I cannot change the "select * from" command. The column names are dynamic.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to contain more about how it is dynamic? How the view is defined and if it is the same column every time that has the issue>

Comment: Can you show me pelase how is your dynamic query built ??

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tbl varchar(max) = 'table_or_view_name'

declare @cols varchar(max) =
    (select case when data_type='varchar' then 'REPLACE('+column_name+',''"'','''')' else column_name end+char(10)+','
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = @tbl for xml path(''))

declare @sql varchar(max)='select '+left(@cols,len(@cols)-1)+' from '+@tbl

print @sql
exec(@sql)
```